# How to wait between 2 API calls in RestAssured framework

Tags: java, wait, rest-assured

Scenario: I need to wait for 10 secs in between calling 2 APIs. Because BE takes time to update and if we call the second API immediately, it does not give the expected output.

I used `Thread.sleep` for the wait and it is working fine, but wanted to check if there is any other way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Awaitility** lib is what you want, it waits based on condition (similar to Explicit wait in selenium).

User guide here: https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ScheduledExecutorService** class:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

executorService.schedule(Classname::someTask, delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or **TimeUnit.sleep()** which is quite similar to the Thread.sleep() you're already using:

```
try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(secondsToSleep);
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

http://www.awaitility.org/

```
Awaitility.await().pollDelay(Duration.ofMillis(retryIntervalMillis)).until(() -> true);
```

OR

Guava (note possible SonarQube issue):  https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Uninterruptibles.html